# require lib in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a file alert_import in lib/models/alert_import', I would like to use in my task sth like this:

```
task :send_automate_alerts => :environment do
 # STDERR.puts "Path is #{$:}"
  Rake.application.rake_require '../../lib/models/alert_import'
  ai = AlertImport::Alert.new(2)
  ai.send_email_with_notifcations
end
```

In this code I get error:

Can't find ../../lib/models/alert_import

in AlertImport I have:

```
module AlertImport

  class Alert

    def initialize(number_days)
      @number_days = number_days
    end

    def get_all_alerts
      alerts = { }
      Organization.automate_import.each do |o|
        last_import = o.import_histories.where(import_type: "automate").last
        last_successful_import = ImportHistory.last_automate_successful_import(o)
        if last_import
          if last_import.created_at + @number_days.days >= Time.now
            alerts[o.id] ="Error during last automate import Last successful import was #{ last_successful_import ? last_successful_import.created_at : "never"}" if last_import.status == "failure"
            alerts[o.id] ="Error during last automate import - status pending Last successful import was #{ last_successful_import ? last_successful_import.created_at : "never"}" if last_import.status == "pending"
          else
            alerts[o.id] = "There were no new files uploaded within #{@number_days} days"
          end
        else
          alerts[o.id] = "The import was never triggered at all"
        end
      end
      alerts
    end

    def send_email_with_notifcations
      alerts =get_all_alerts
      unless alerts.empty?
        AlertMailer.email_notifications(alerts).deliver
      end
    end

  end

end
```

The correct solution is:

```
desc "Send alerts about automate imports"

task :send_automate_alerts => :environment do
  require "#{Rails.root}/lib/models/alert_import"
  ai = AlertImport::Alert.new(2)
  ai.send_email_with_notifcations
end
```

Comment: Your path is wrong then.

Answer (score 9):

In Rails 3.x, I've had success by first importing the file using `require` and then including the module to the namespace. Here's how it would look:

```
require 'models/alert_import'

namespace :alerts

  include AlertImport

  desc 'Send alerts about automate imports'
  task send_automate_alerts: :environment do
    ai = AlertImport::Alert.new(2)
    ai.send_email_with_notifcations
  end

end
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried a few options, most notably trying [`rake require`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Rake/Application/rake_require), but it looks like the documentation for `rake_require` is incorrect. It specifically will not include files that don't end in `.rake`

So in the end, I did it "from scratch" - something like this:
```

```
namespace :my_namespace do
  task :my_task do
    require File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'services', 'my_module.rb')

    class Wrapper
      include MyModule
    end
    Wrapper.new.the_method_I_need(args)
  end
end
```

Done.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably your path wrong, you can do as follow

```
task :send_automate_alerts => :environment do
 # STDERR.puts "Path is #{$:}"
  Rake.application.rake_require "#{Rails.root}/lib/models/alert_import"
  ai = AlertImport::Alert.new(2)
  ai.send_email_with_notifcations
end
```

`"#{Rails.root}"` this will give you the current path of your project

Comment: It doesn't help I have corret path but the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Your path is wrong, you can try:

```
task :send_automate_alerts => :environment do
 # STDERR.puts "Path is #{$:}"
  Rake.application.rake_require "#{Rails.root}/lib/models/alert_import"
  ai = AlertImport::Alert.new(2)
  ai.send_email_with_notifcations
end
```

Regards!

Comment: works require "#{Rails.root}/lib/models/alert_import" ( it does not error ) , but now cannot see model : uninitialized constant AlertImport::Alert::Organization ( Organization is in database)

Comment: I think that the error with your path is fixed. You must make other question and accept this response if you have fix the error with path. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check out there http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/Application.html#M000099
define correct path