# include an module from rails app into rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have a module in rails project on `app/lib/md.rb` and I want to import and use it in a rake task outside of application scope under `lib/task` directory. the `app` and `lib` folders are in same directory, in the other work it's like below:

```
- app
  - lib
    - md.rb
- lib
  - task
```

my module is just couple of class and my rake task is like below:

```
include Md

task :import_product do
    puts ''
    puts '=================='
    puts 'Started Fetching Products'
    puts '=================='
...
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [require lib in rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455884/require-lib-in-rake-task)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a possible duplicate, but nevertheless

```
task :import_product do
    require File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'lib', 'md.rb')
    Md.hurray
    puts ''
    puts '=================='
    puts 'Started Fetching Products'
    puts '=================='
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one file to load from app/ folder its better to load with the **environment** in your rake task.

```
task import_product: :environment do
  ...
  ...
  ...
end
```

Hope it helps!